# How to get the anonymousType dataItem from gridview_RowDeleting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

i want to get the Id from **GridView**  in **RowDeleting** Event , I tried like this:

```
        protected void gvHouse_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Guid hholder = (Guid)(e.Values[0]);

            using (var dataContext = new realtydbEntities())
            {
                var house = (from h in dataContext.Households.Include("aspnet_Users.aspnet_Membership")
                             where h.HouseholdID == hholder
                             select h).First();
                dataContext.DeleteObject(house);
                dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work.

the anonymous type is like this, AND I use a List<**this anonymousType**> to bind to **GridView**'s datasource:

```
                         new
                         {
                             Id = u.HouseholdID,
                             BuNo = u.Building.BuildingName,
                             UnNo = u.UnitNo,
                             DepNo = u.DepartmentNo,
                             Name = u.aspnet_Users.UserName,
                             Corp = u.Corporation,
                             IdNumber = u.IdNumber,
                             Telephone = u.Telephone,
                             OtherHouseMembers = u.OtherHouseMembers,
                             OtherInfo = u.OtherInfo,
                             CrDate = u.aspnet_Users.aspnet_Membership.CreateDate
                         });
```

i want to get the anonymous object or just get the ID property's value.

Comment: how are you binding data to gridview ?

Comment: @Habib.OSU i use List<this-anonymouseType> binding to gridview

Comment: @Kevin "It doesn't work" is a very broad statement.  Do you get a compile error?  A runtime exception?  No exception but incorrect behavior?  Details, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get you the ID

```
 var HouseHoldid = Guid.Parse(gvHouse.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
```

if ID is of type int then:

```
 var HouseHoldid = Convert.ToInt32(gvHouse.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
```

After deleting you have to refresh the datasource as well. Remove the item from the binded list and refresh the datasource for the gridview

Comment: Last time I checked, it was not possible to convert a string to a Guid by casting.

Comment: @phoog, I just followed his example, you are right I am going to remove it

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .net 4 you can take advantage of the `dynamic` type like this:

```
// Get the reference to the bound item
dynamic item = gvHouse.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItem; 
// Access item property
var itemId = item.Id;
```

Keep in mind that none of the properties of your type will be available via intellisense, you'll just have to avoid typos.

Comment: not work, "RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

Answer (score 0):

this way can get the datasource

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable sourceData = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;

    sourceData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
}
```